# ASP.NET Identity user creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Just for general understanding, I don't get it why it's been set once to create an ApplicationUser with username and eMail and on the other hand separately a UserManager, which then sets the password:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Btw: I have just created an empty .NET 4.6.1 Application and try to figure out now the different parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UserManager will hash the password, and save the hashed password in the database.

Comment: okay, but why can't I then just simply add the application user which inherits from IdentityUser and have that as setter function? Or at least just letting the UserManager only save it to the DB and do the rest in the IdentityUser?

Comment: The IdentityUser gives you the public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }.  This is what the UserManager populates after hashing the model.Password parameter in the CreateAsync method.  UserManager also has manager.PasswordValidator (see the ApplicationUserManager Create method).  So it handles extra pieces of functionality here.